# How to get MS Excel to list files in a folder with their metadata (in particular, the tags created for the files)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have zero experience with VBA or Python. I will use whichever method that can help solve the problem (mentioned in the title) in the quickest/simplest possible way.

How to get MS Excel to list files in a folder with their metadata (in particular, the tags created for the files)?

Thanks!

Comment: And if  you have zero experience in VBA or Python, how will use the code that we could provide???

Answer (score -1):

Well, just use this in VBA

```
Sub test()
    Dim FD As FileDialog
    Dim i

    Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With FD
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each i In .SelectedItems
                MsgBox FileLastModified(i)
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Function FileLastModified(ByVal strFullFileName As String)
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim f As Object
    Dim s As String

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(strFullFileName)

    s = UCase(strFullFileName) & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Last Modified: " & f.DateLastModified
    FileLastModified = s
    'f.DateCreated
    'f.DateLastModified

    Set fs = Nothing: Set f = Nothing
End Function
```